# Como fazer o JavaScript ler um valor dado por um usuário?

Tags: javascript

Como que eu faço para o JavaScript ler o que o usuário digita? Como se fosse o `leia()` do Portugol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o método `prompt()` para colher dados numa pop-up, e `alert()` para mostrar algo numa pop-up:

```js
var texto = prompt('insira texto aqui');
alert(texto);
```

Answer (score 1):

No código abaixo (não usei jQuery) existem dois eventos: um para detectar a tecla no momento em que o valor é digitado no `input`, e outro para detectar o clique no botão "Enviar".

```js
// Função que mostra o valor do input num alert
function mostrarValor() {
    alert(document.getElementById("meu-input").value);
}

// Evento que é executado toda vez que uma tecla for pressionada no input
document.getElementById("meu-input").onkeypress = function(e) {
    // 13 é a tecla <ENTER>. Se ela for pressionada, mostrar o valor
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        mostrarValor();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

// Evento que é executado ao clicar no botão de enviar
document.getElementById("meu-submit").onclick = function(e) {
    mostrarValor();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" id="meu-input" />
    <input type="submit" id="meu-submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```